# List of Physical Toys

Tags: soft-question, education, home-experiment, big-list, popular-science

There should be a list of toys considered "physical", which demonstrate or make you think over certain physical principles/phenomena. And of course which could just amaze.

Related question at MSE is ["Mathematical toys?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100051/mathematical-toys)

Comment: Big-lists are not constructive by default. Yes, excpetions have been made but those are exceptions. Take it up on meta if you feel there should be one in this case, but personally I'm agin' it.

Comment: don't forget http://www.arborsci.com/astro-blaster

Answer (score 4):

[Rattleback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rattleback) behavior is quite tricky to explain.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, Bohr and Pauli consider [tippe tops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tippe_top) to be fascinating.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wissenschaft-shop.de](http://www.wissenschaft-shop.de/out/pictures/wysiwigpro/802265_Pauli_Bohr-Wendekrei.jpg))</sub>

Also, [magnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction#After_electroweak_symmetry_breaking) behavior is quite tricky to explain.

Answer (score 3):

[Levitron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levitron) --- toy that displays the phenomenon known as spin stabilized magnetic levitation. The most simple variant is the most amazing --- no batteries, no electronics --- it just flies! Magnet repulsion + gyroscopic stabilization.

Answer (score 3):

[Stirling engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_engine) of all kinds. Low temperature Stirling engines can work on the heat from hot cup (["coffee cup stirling engine"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yvmiyik55D8&hd=1)) or even from body heat.